# Idiomatic Julia and the return keyword

Tags: julia

Coming to Julia from Python I am looking for something that sort of sets the standard for idiomatic Julia.  In the Python world there is PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  I am looking for the equivalent in the Julia world.

For example, the Python statement on use of `return` at above link is:

> Be consistent in return statements. Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should. If any return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no value is returned should explicitly state this as return None, and an explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function (if reachable).

The closest I have found to a PEP 8 in the Julia world is the **Style Guide** section of the Julio 1.0.0 documentation [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Style-Guide-1). I did not see a discussion regarding the use of `return` there.

**Question**: Is there something more that someone can steer me to?

**Question**: Is it considered idiomatic Julian to always use the `return` reserved word at the end of a function?

Comment: I don't think that a unique style guide has emerged yet. Personally I almost always use explicit `return` statements (I sometimes omit it in very short methods). I find things are too implicit otherwise. My function might actually be subtlely type unstable.

Comment: Your best bet thusfar is to read [Julia base source code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/tree/master/base). A little extreme, but they, ironically, show no consistency with return statements: lines 102 & 112 [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/filesystem.jl)

Comment: Yup, two identical returns of `nothing`, 10 lines apart, and one is `return nothing` and the other is `nothing`.  Thanks for the pointer.  I like  the comments  here suggesting that an explicit `return` should be used most of the time.

Comment: I follow a simple rule: short-form one-line functions: no `return`. Ordinary long-form functions: _always_ `return`.  I find implicit `return`s disorienting, and always keep thinking that it must be a statement that has some invisible side-effect, before realizing, 'oh, I guess it's just a `return` statement'.  But it is in _very_ common use, even among core devs, unfortunately.

Comment: I concur.  Seems like Julia needs something like PEP 8 in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time, making the `return` explicit is good practice.  There are occasions when a function is not intended to return a value (like `print`); Julia provides a way to make this explicit `return nothing`.  With short functions that are essentially elaborated conditionals `if x != 0 ... end`, letting each branch of the conditional return its value without explicitly using `return` is done, but nothing is lost and clarity is often gained by making the `return` explicit.